# JQuery fires alert more than once when $.html() is used to populate content

Tags: jquery

I have this little problem that I cannot wrap my head around.

I have a click event that fires when an element is clicked like so:

```
$(document).on("click", "#PersonalVault", function (e) {
    alert("hit");
    $("#Content").html("...other html with script...");
});
```

Some sample html data that gets inserted in #Content:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        alert("content hit");
    });
</script>
<div>
    ...more html...
</div>
```

The alert("hit") fires only once, which is good, but alert("content hit") will fire more than once after I clicked it again.

So, the first #PersonalVault click, it adds the html to #Content, and everything works fine.
Second click on #PersonalVault, will fire alert("content hit") twice.
Third click... 3 times... and so on. But alert("hit") will continue to fire only once.

Any idea how I can fix this problem?
Let me know if it is still unclear so that I can elaborate a bit more.
Any help will be very much appreciated!

Comment: I think we need a little more code, but look at this. https://jsfiddle.net/1hexabzo/ 
Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: @theblindprophet You should re-read the question. He asked why does `alert("content hit")` fired multiple times.

Comment: _"Some sample html data that gets inserted in #Content:"_  Is `$(document).ready(function () {
        alert("content hit");
    });` set as `html` of `#Content` at each click ? _"Any idea how I can fix this problem? Let me know if it is still unclear so that I can elaborate a bit more."_ Yes, still unclear. Can you create a stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: All I did was put the code provided into a JS fiddle and it works. I understand what is problem is, but we also do not have enough code to diagnose it.

Comment: @theblindprophet Appears OP is also including a `<script>` tag at `#Content` `html` which contains call to `.ready()` ?

Comment: @FrederickMoller Can you reproduce the issue at stacksnippets or jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Yes please reproduce problem

Comment: Hi all, yes I will try and reproduce in jsfiddle. Will update my post soon.

Comment: Cannot reproduce https://jsfiddle.net/d5nca387/

Comment: Sorry, I don't know why, but I cannot reproduce this in jsfiddle. In my local project however it is duplicating the events on every click.

Comment: @FrederikMoller if you answer your own question, you should post it as an actual answer instead of editing it into the question. Then you can mark your answer accepted so people can tell it's been solved

Comment: Oh yes, thank you, for telling me, I'm so tired I cannot think straight :)

Answer (score 1):

So I have found my problem. The problem was that the #Content's HTML that is being inserted, contained an event:

```
$(document).on('click', '#ViewItem', function () {
    alert("item viewed");
});
```

It looks like if I use this, the jquery gets added to the main document as well.

The fix was just to change this event to:

```
$('#ViewItem').click(function () {
    alert("item viewed");
});
```

Thanks for everyone's input in the comments!